# algpseudocode font size

Tags: fontsize, algorithms, algorithmicx

I want to change the default font size of the algorithm in `algpseudocode` environment to small. This is because my algorithm is lengthy and i have page limitations. Please help

Answer (score 9):

Package `algorithmicx` provides hooks for use before and after the pseudocode: `\ALG@beginalgorithmic` and `\ALG@endalgorithmic`. You can redefine them to suit your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@beginalgorithmic}{\small}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State $x \gets 42$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Note that other `algorithmicx` layouts may redefine the commands. Also note that this doesn't affect line number size, which is controlled by `\alglinenumber`.